# How can I analyze the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity for nested loops

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=log(i); j++) {
        O(1);
    }
}
```

where `n` is given by user?  Does the time complexity depend on the loop  variables only or the conditional `<=` also?

Comment: What does "Does time complexity depend on increment variable of loop only or comparing part all so" mean? Exactly where are you stuck computing the time complexity?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I've edited your post to fix the grammar, and made your algorithm complete by putting some `O(1)` code in the inner most loop.  I also removed the salutations at the beginning and end of your post - that's just how we do things on Stack Overflow.  I did have to make some assumptions about what you actually meant by "increment variable of loop" and "comparing part"; if I assumed incorrectly, please [edit] to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is usually independent of user input (in this case: n).
First loop will perform n iterations and second loop will perform log(n) iterations at worst case.
Since you did not provide the loop body, assuming the operations in the loop is O(1), then the complexity is O(n log n).

Regarding your second question, it depends on both your loop and "comparing part" (loop body).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity depends on everything that takes time, so yes, it depends on the bounds of the `for` loop.  It generally works best to analyze loops from the inside out.  So

```
    for (j=1; j<=log(i); j++) {
        O(1);
    }
```

will take `O(1)*log(i)=O(log(i))` time.  Then we can write the whole loop as

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    O(log(i));
}
```

The easiest thing at this point is to just add it all up.  The total time is therefore:

```
 O(log(1))+O(log(2))+O(log(3))+...+O(log(n-2))+O(log(n-1))+O(log(n))
=O(log(1) +  log(2) +  log(3) +...+  log(n-2) +  log(n-1) +  log(n))
```

Because of the properties of logarithms, this is `O(log(n!))`, and by [Stirling’s approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), this is `O(n log(n))`.